# Making an image move from one view controller to another

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller

In the native Photos app on the iPhone, when I share an image by email, a nice animation sequence happens:

1. The image shrinks to the center of the screen
2. the mail composer slides UNDER the image
3. the image is scaled and positioned in the message

How can I achieve a similar effect with my own view controllers? My situation is that I have the image in view controller A, I want to present view controller B modally by sliding it in UNDER the image, and then move the image onto its position within view controller B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the imageView from ViewController A and add it to the keyWindow object
2. Present ViewController B modally
3. Add the ImageView to ViewController B after the animation finishes

Comment: My bad - i tried this and it didn't work, and then found I was not calling:  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
in the AppDelegate. Thanks for the amazingly quick and good answer!